# Android vs ASP.NET vs Bootstrap

Tags: android, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have created a small site on ASP.NET some time ago.

I have used:
ASP.NET and Bootstrap.

The issue is that all worked fine for few mounths, but today i have noticed that if i request Full Website version in Google Chrome on Android the site doesn't adapt.

All works fine on WP, iOS and even Android 4.4 with Chrome 51.0.2704.81

But my phone shows site not adapted to the screen size. My phone is Android 6.0.1 and Chrome is 52.0.2743.98

On desktop if i resize the Google Chrome window, the site gets adapted.

I have read some articles on stackoverflow, my index.html contains this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Here how it should look and looks on all devices:

[image]

Here how it looks on my Android 6.0.1 and Chrome is 52.0.2743.98:

[image]